# Replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are EQUAL to some values

Tags: python, numpy

I know how to replace all elements of numpy array that are greater than some values,
like `array[array > 0] = 0`, but I don't really know how to replace all elements that are **equal** to some values without using `for` loop, like below can achieve what I want but is there any way not to use the `for` loop?

Sorry for being unclear, `some_values` here is a list, like `[7, 8, 9]`

```
for v in some_values:
    array[array == v] = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
array[np.isin(array, some_values)] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
a[a==replacee] = replacer
```

For 1:1 replacements without any for loop. Numpy is meant to be vectorized & each operation is performed this way so you don't need for loops.

In case you want to replace a whole list of values with a single one, you might use `isin()` as follows:

```
a[a.isin(replacee_list)] = replacer
```

In case you want to use a set of values with another set of values from a different array, use:

```
a = np.copyto(a, replacer_array, where = a.isin(replacee_list))
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. This is identical to the inside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah its identical to whats inside the loop but eliminating the loop is the answer.

Comment: How is it eliminating the for loop? Did you try your code when `some_values` is a iterable, e.g. a list?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I updated the question, `some_values` here is a list, like [7, 8, 9]

Comment: Ohh With the updated question, I see the problem now. If there is a whole list to compare of course single comparison wont work and `isin()` is the way to go!